# How to "fly" with elytra in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the Minecraft 1.9 snapshots, elytra have been added. They allow you to glide, but they don't allow you to fly. Since you can't fly with elytra, I'm looking for an alternative way to "fly" with them. Has anyone got a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an item that gives the player a jump boost when held. First, execute the following commands:

```
/scoreboard objectives add FlyingOrb dummy
/scoreboard objectives add FlyingOrb2 dummy
```

Then, put the following commands in a command block chain:

```
/scoreboard players set @a FlyingOrb2 0 {OnGround:1b}
/scoreboard players set @a FlyingOrb2 1 {SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"Flying Orb"}}}}
/effect @a[score_FlyingOrb_min=1,score_FlyingOrb2=0] clear

/scoreboard players set @a FlyingOrb 0 {OnGround:1b}
/scoreboard players set @a FlyingOrb 1 {OnGround:1b, SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"Flying Orb"}}}}
/scoreboard players set @a FlyingOrb 2 {OnGround:0b, SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"Flying Orb"}}}}
/effect @a[score_FlyingOrb_min=1,score_FlyingOrb=1] minecraft:jump_boost 1 40
/effect @a[score_FlyingOrb_min=2,score_FlyingOrb=2] minecraft:jump_boost 1 255
```

Finally, use an anvil to name a random item "Flying Orb", hold it, jump, and fly away. The code protects you from fall damage, so you won't get hurt if you fall down hard, with or without elytra equipped. The fall damage protection works even if you let go of the item in mid air.

If your computer has trouble running 8 commands each tick, you could remove the first block of code. However, doing so will allow you to jump boosted without fall damage protection if you've just let go of the item, so you have to wait one second after letting go of the item before jumping again.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold a Punch II Bow and as you are moving forward, shoot slightly ahead and up of yourself. Try to hit yourself with the arrow, and it will propel you into the air. Wear protective armor as the damage will add up over time.

Answer (score 0):

I also added a repeating command block that does /effect @p 8 1000000 10
it helps so you don't have to type that in every time someone dies. You might get a little lag depending on what type of computer you use.